# Dynamically creating menus in Adobe Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

I have a Flex application and need to generate a menu programatically, it will be quite complex and dynamic.  What is the best technique for doing this?

UPDATE : I've tested out the code below using objects for the menu items and children properties as RIAstar suggested.  This is working except I don't see the "Input" menu, it seems to be bypassed.   What I see is:

[image: Screenshot]

I was expecting "Add->Input->Device{0..8}".

Thanks for any ideas, Fred.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Menu;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var toplevelMenu:Object = new Object();
            toplevelMenu.label = "Top Level";
            var addMenu:Object = new Object();
            addMenu.label = "Add";
            toplevelMenu.children = addMenu;

            var inputMenu:Object = new Object();
            inputMenu.label = "Input";

            var inputDevicesMenu:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            for (var i:int = 0;i < 10;i++) {
                if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                    var inputDeviceMenu:Object = new Object();
                    inputDeviceMenu.label = "Device " + i;
                    inputDevicesMenu.addItem(inputDeviceMenu);
                }
            }
            if (inputDevicesMenu.length > 0) {
                inputMenu.children = inputDevicesMenu;
            }
            addMenu.children = [inputMenu];

            var menu:Menu = Menu.createMenu(this, toplevelMenu, false);
            menu.show(event.stageX, event.stageY);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button x="56" y="28" label="Show Menu" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: The [Menu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Menu.html) class does this out of the box (there's no Spark equivalent though).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  My question is if I have for example 5 levels deep of menus if I use the above techniques I'll have to keep 5 object references and chain a bunch of .appendChild calls.  Just wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at now. You'll have to create the hierarchical structure _some_ way. Note that it doesn't _have_ to be XML: it could be an Array or IList with a `children` property (I think). Perhaps you would like that more.

Comment: I've updated my app. with the objects and children property as you suggested, it's working except on of the intermediate menus : "inputs" is not showing up.  Would really like to know why as I need this in the finished product.

Comment: The `children` property should be a collection of some kind, so something like `addMenu.children = [inputMenu];` instead of `addMenu.children = inputMenu;`

Comment: I just modified to use the brackets as you suggested, sill the input menu does not show up.  Could you try running my example above?

Comment: What happens if you comment out 'inputMenu.children = inputDevicesMenu'?

Comment: **all** the `children` properties of course; not just the one I mentioned as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per RIAstar suggestion and you code, i have made some modification in button1_clickHandler function: -

Updated code in function button1_clickHandler: -

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var addMenu:Object = new Object();
                addMenu.label = "Add";

                var inputMenu:Object = new Object();
                inputMenu.label = "Input";

                var outputMenu:Object = new Object();
                outputMenu.label = "Output";

                var inputOutputDevicesMenu:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                inputOutputDevicesMenu.addItem(outputMenu);
                inputOutputDevicesMenu.addItem(inputMenu);

                addMenu.children = inputOutputDevicesMenu;

                var inputDevicesMenu:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                for (var i:int = 0;i < 10;i++) {
                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        var inputDeviceMenu:Object = new Object();
                        inputDeviceMenu.label = "Device " + i;
                        inputDevicesMenu.addItem(inputDeviceMenu);
                    }
                }
                if (inputDevicesMenu.length > 0) {
                    inputMenu.children = inputDevicesMenu;
                }

                var menu:Menu = Menu.createMenu(this, addMenu, true);
                menu.show(event.stageX, event.stageY);
            }
```

Hope this may help to get some idea......